# Registar a hora do logout na tabela das sessões

Tags: php, mysql

Estou a registar os dados na tabela da base de dados sempre que há um login, mas pretendo fazer `update` na hora do `logout`.
Para fazer o insert, faço-o na ao validar o login do utilizador:

```
  if(isset($resultado)){
        $_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $resultado['id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'] = $resultado['niveis_acesso_id'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'] = $resultado['email'];
        $_SESSION['usuarioSenha'] = $resultado['senha'];
        $data_hora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $_SESSION['acesso'] = $data_hora;
        $tempolimite = 2;
        $_SESSION['registro'] = time();
        $_SESSION['limite'] = $tempolimite;

        $teste1 = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];
        $teste2 = $_SESSION['usuarioNome'];
        $teste3 = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $queries = "INSERT INTO raddb.sessoes (iduser, user, data, ip) VALUES ('$teste1', '$teste2', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '$teste3')"; 
        $teste = mysqli_query( $conn, $queries);
```

Onde criei a `Session` com a data do login desta forma:

```
        $data_hora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $_SESSION['acesso'] = $data_hora;
```

Na página `sair` estou a fazer desta forma:

```
session_start();
require("conexao.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
$teste1 = $_SESSION['usuarioId'];
$teste2 = $_SESSION['acesso'];
$date = strtotime($teste2); 
$teste3 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);

$sql = "UPDATE raddb.sessoes SET datafim = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' WHERE iduser = $teste1 AND data = $teste3";
 $teste = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);
unset(
    $_SESSION['usuarioId'],
    $_SESSION['usuarioNome'],
    $_SESSION['usuarioNiveisAcessoId'],
    $_SESSION['usuarioEmail'],
    $_SESSION['usuarioSenha']
);

$_SESSION['logindeslogado'] = "Deslogado com sucesso";
//redirecionar o usuario para a página de login
header("Location: ./index.php/login");
```

Estou a colocar no where a condição da data (tipo datetime) do login porque se colocar apenas a condição `iduser = $teste1` faz `update` a todas as linhas que tenha aquele `id`. Para que isso não aconteça tenho de ter a condição da data e hora do login, mas com as duas condições não faz `update` na tabela. Na página sair estou a converter a variável `$teste2 = $_SESSION['acesso'];` para `datetime`, mas nem assim faz o `update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a mesma variável de sessão para armazenar e recuperar o registro no banco.

**EDIT**:

```
$queries = "INSERT INTO raddb.sessoes (iduser, user, data, ip) VALUES ('$teste1', '$teste2', '$data_hora', '$teste3')";
```

> Note que a sua variável `$data_hora` está entre aspas simples, ou seja, está sendo tratada como `string`.

Na página `sair` altere os seguintes valores:

```
$data_hora = $_SESSION['acesso'];
```

E atualize a query de update:

```
$sql = "UPDATE raddb.sessoes SET datafim = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' WHERE iduser = $teste1 AND data = '$data_hora'";
```

> Perceba que a variável `$data_hora` está novamente entre aspas.

Comment: fiz a alteração que sugeriu e na página sair experimentei mantendo tudo como tenho na pergunta e sem esta parte de código `$date = strtotime($teste2); 
    $teste3 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);`, mas não faz o update na mesma da data e hora do fim

Comment: @Bruno, você está passando no update a variável `$teste2` para o valor data?

Comment: estou a fazer assim no where: `WHERE iduser = $teste1 AND data = $teste2"`, mas mesmo assim não faz o update

Comment: já funcionou... Qual foi a diferença na atualização da sua resposta

Comment: @Bruno, adicionei a explicação na própria resposta.

Comment: pode ajudar nesta pergunta [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391333/enviar-para-p%C3%A1gina-login-automaticamente)